# Failure to find org.apache.xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 in http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/

Tags: java, maven, xalan

I am running a maven project that I downloaded it from https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/suresh/saml2/sso-demo/src-dist
The problem is that, it can run on another computer but mine :( . I don't know why. When I enter "mvn clean install" in the command line. The result is as following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Travelocity.com SAML2 SP Maven Webapp
[INFO] Avis.Com SAML2 SP Maven Webapp
[INFO] SAML2.SSO.Demo Maven Project
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Travelocity.com SAML2 SP Maven Webapp 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 is missing, no dependency
 information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Travelocity.com SAML2 SP Maven Webapp ............. FAILURE [0.388s]
[INFO] Avis.Com SAML2 SP Maven Webapp .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] SAML2.SSO.Demo Maven Project ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.579s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 04 18:10:45 ICT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project saml2.sso.demo.travelocity.com: Could
not resolve dependencies for project org.wso2.identity:saml2.sso.demo.travelocit
y.com:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 in ht
tp://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, reso
lution will not be reattempted until the update interval of xerces-api has elaps
ed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
```

Seems it failed to download xalan.jar from [a link](http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/) . But I saw that maven automatically downloaded xalan-2.7.1.jar already. 
I don't know how to fix this bug. Please help me as soon as possible. I'm very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository your project is searching on does not contain the artifact :

`org.apache.xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1`.

It only contains `xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1`.

If you run `mvn -X compile` you'll see they are a dependency of:

```
[DEBUG]    org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xerces:xml-apis:jar:2.9.1:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xerces:resolver:jar:2.9.1:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xerces:serializer:jar:2.9.1:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime
```

If believe the person who wrote this code meant to exclude them:

```
<exclusion>
     <groupId>xalan</groupId>
     <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
     <groupId>xerces</groupId>
     <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

But note that the `<groupId>` is actually excluding a dependency that it's not really a dependency. You will need to change the above exclusions in the pom, by:

```
<exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
     <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
     <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Follow the same pattern for other potential conflicting artifacts.

Comment: Please tell me how to fix this in details. I can't figure out how to deal with this :(

Comment: Do you see the problem with the groupIDs?

Comment: I'm quite new on SAML, so I don't know how to do :(
I choose another way that I build a project in netbeans by copying files to it. But I still have errors :(